Should I revise this sentence?
Is it necessary to revise this sentence in bold?
Should I use “would have destroyed” and “had approached” instead of “would destroy” and “approached” in the following sentence in bold?
"At the end of WW1, countries didn’t use airships for large-scale airstrikes anymore. Improved anti-aircraft cannons would easily destroy slow, large airships if they approached any major city."

It's not necessary to use the Perfect form would have destroyed in your context, but most people probably would. Note that if we changed countries didn’t use airships to countries rarely used airships, it would be at the very least "non-idiomatic" to use the Perfect. The Perfect here implies airships were never in fact used, but I don't know what the ground truth is in this matter. The reason you don't need it is simply that it's already explicitly stated that airships weren't used, so that doesn't need to be repeated through the Perfect verb form.

@FumbleFingers so you mean if airships were often destroyed so countries stopped using them for air strikes, then “would destroy” would be fine because airships were indeed once used?

...note that pedantic grammarians could make a case for ...if they had approached any major city or even full-blown subjunctive ...if they were to have approached any major city, but my advice is if you don't need a more complex verb form, don't use it.

Does this answer your question? Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?

I mean that for you as a learner, it's better to just assume you don't need the Perfect here, so don't use it.

Would it change the meaning? Would destroy vs would have destroyed

Proofreading  is off-topic, but I'll just mention that no longer used airships sounds better than didn't use... any more. Presumably  airships ceased to be used because they were found by experience to be too vulnerable. The cannon would destroy them while they were still being used, or would have destroyed them if they had continued to be used.

As I said, the meaning is already explicitly given by countries didn’t use airships. That's why in your exact context it makes no difference whether you use cannons would easily destroy airships or cannons would have easily destroyed airships. And as I also explained, if it had been countries rarely used airships, it would actually be wrong to use the Perfect. But if it had been countries avoided using airships, that would be potentially ambiguous (maybe they sometimes used them). In which case using the Perfect or not would "disambiguate" the meaning.
